# how to show moodle quiz to the users only without entering the other links in the moodle?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

how to show moodle quiz to the users only without entering the other links in the moodle ?
i want users enter to the test directly without accessing the other links in the site .
General structure

```
Default to "Array
(
)
" //the data to be saved
list of ( 
  object {
    name string   //data name
    value string   //data value
  } 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect()` function. Using this you can redirect users from one page to another page.

OR

Override the default login page by setting `$CFG->alternateloginurl` via the admin interface at `/admin/settings.php?section=manageauths`. Any redirects after users login will automatically point to your custom location instead.